# Build failure - Apache Parquet-MR source (mvn install failure)

Tags: apache, maven, maven-3, velocity, parquet

I am getting following error while trying to execute "mvn clean install" for building parquet-mr source obtained from https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr

```
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) @ parquet-generator ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Parquet MR ................................. SUCCESS [1.494s]
[INFO] Apache Parquet Generator .......................... FAILURE [0.064s]
[INFO] Apache Parquet Common ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Encodings .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Column ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Jackson ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hadoop ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Avro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Benchmarks ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Pig ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Thrift ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Cascading .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Pig Bundle ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Protobuf ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Scala .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Scrooge ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hadoop Bundle ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Binding Parent ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Binding Interface ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive 0.10 Binding .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive 0.12 Binding .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Binding Factory ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Binding Bundle ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Storage Handler ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Hive Bundle ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Parquet Tools .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.826s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jul 05 15:55:33 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/365M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.5:process (default) on project parquet-generator: Error rendering velocity resource. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :parquet-generator
```

"mvn --version" is:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-17 20:52:22+0530)
Maven home: /Users/.../maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Can someone guide me on the same ? Any help on this is highly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the latest maven-filtering plugin version. If the error is caused by a plugin who uses maven-filtering as implicit dependency you should declare its dependency(for example maven-remote-resources-plugin:

```
         <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
         </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
```

Source http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Java-8-and-possible-TomEE-1-7-0-td4668490i20.html

Answer (score 5):

This seems caused by a maven bug with Java 8:

[[MSHARED-319] Filtering throws NPE when using JDK8](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHARED-319)

A workaround is using Java 7.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This was the problem. I switched to Java 7 and the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following URL:
https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@parquet.apache.org/msg00967.html

I had the same error in building Apache Parquet from https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr, but 1.8.0rc1 was successfully built(https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/archive/parquet-1.8.0rc1.zip)

Answer (score -2):

Using the following command will do.

```
mvn install --batch-mode -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dsource.skip=true
```