# Parquet file reader

Tags: java, hadoop, parquet

I was looking for small poc code for reading parquet file.
I downloaded the git sample code which is provided in Parquet-mr. I am not able to build the code.

My environment is :

Maven 2.2.1, Java 8

---

### BUILD ERROR

Error rendering velocity resource.

Look like same issue with this post as well

[Build failure - Apache Parquet-MR source (mvn install failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229445/build-failure-apache-parquet-mr-source-mvn-install-failure)

so I started checking something else. I got to know that hive exec 1.2.1 jar also has support to read the parquet files.

Should I use it to read the parquet files?

Comment: Checked with maven 3.3 and java 1.7. Now it is showing me expcetion:Failed to execute goal org.apache.thrift.tools:maven-thrift-plugin:0.1.10:testCompile (thrift-sources) on project parquet-thrift: thrift did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]
he.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.thrift.tools:maven-thrift-plugin:0.1.10:testCompile (thrift-sources) on project parquet-thrift: thrift did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information.

Comment: Can some one let me know if I am missing any configuration parameters? WIth the help of hive exec jar I am able to read the files

Comment: You need to install thrift first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Generate Parquet File Using Pure Java (Including Date & Decimal Types) And Upload to S3 \[Windows\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355038/how-to-generate-parquet-file-using-pure-java-including-date-decimal-types-an)

Comment: I have already installed Thrift and still receive the same error.